# Using PHP configured for Apache with IIS

Tags: apache-2.2, php, iis-7

Here's my problem, I recently had to use IIS7 for one of my clients but he also wants PHP which is currently installed for my Apache setup on there. I can't find any ISAPI files in there, so I don't know what to do here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all your IIS7 + PHP needs start here:

> [PHP on IIS7 : The Official Microsoft IIS Site](http://php.iis.net/)

The simplest way to install PHP on IIS7 is just to browse to that site on your server and click the big blue "Install PHP" button. This will launch the Web Platform Installer which will guide your through the install process.

To do this manually see this article:

> [Using FastCGI to Host PHP Applications on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/)

There's also an alternative article on [IIS.NET](http://iis.net):

> [Install and Configure PHP](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/724/install-and-configure-php/)

You will want one of the following binary packages for the "Install and Configure PHP" step:

> [PHP 5.3.6 - VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe - zip](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.3.6-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip)

or

> [PHP 5.2.17 - VC6 x86 Non Thread Safe - zip](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.2.17-nts-Win32-VC6-x86.zip)