# How to install PHP under IIS7.5?

Tags: php, windows, windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using PHP configured for Apache with IIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/285928/using-php-configured-for-apache-with-iis)

I'm trying to install PHP on a new Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, and running into some issues.

All the references I've found make reference to files that are apparently no longer in the PHP distribution (for example, php5isapi.dll), or were written against Windows 2000 or 2003. Microsoft has since changed a lot of things up in the IIS configuration settings in Windows 2008, and so when I look for things they simply aren't there.

Is there an up-to-date guide for installing PHP on Windows Server 2008 anywhere? This is difficult enough without having to figure out the differences between how things work now and 5 years ago.

Comment: All of the ones I see are using an old version of PHP, which I believe to be different from the current version in several important ways. Hence asking for an up to date one, rather than ploughing through a bunch that won't help me.

Answer (score 2):

It is /very/ easy on IIS7 / 7.5 :-)  Check out: http://php.iis.net/

I'm 99% sure you can download and install everything through WebPI.

Comment: Is http://php.iis.net/ an official microsoft thing? I had assumed it was some shady third-party whatsit...

Comment: See my comment to @Lars.

Comment: See the duplicate question for more details, but this is what I went with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an up-to-date guide: http://www.activecollab.com/forums/post/27690/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Links to external sites without any additional information aren't answers, and shouldn't be posted as such. This should have been a comment to the original question, if you weren't going to provide any information in your answer. Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to become familiar with how the site works, and what constitutes an answer. Following the guidelines helps keep SO uncluttered with lots of noise and makes it a very useful resource. Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not agree. To quote the question *Is there an up-to-date guide for installing PHP on Windows Server 2008 anywhere?* - the question was not that hard to answer with google and I don't really feel like just stealing or repeating the content from another site, that answered the question in-depth and thorough. I also do not see anything in the FAQ against posting a reference. What should be criticized are [these comments](http://tinyurl.com/3oqgpr4).

Comment: You're entitled to disagree. Read the FAQ, as I mentioned before. Answers here should be stand-alone and searchable for others to use; if you want to post nothing but a link, it belongs as a comment. I could have just downvoted your non-answer - instead, I tried to point out why it shouldn't be posted as an answer as a favor to you, so you didn't start losing rep for it. (FYI, the question itself is off topic IMO, as it's related to server configuration and not software development (code).)

Comment: Ken is correct - Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Ken_White let's just leave it at that and stop cluttering with off-topic discussions. But please stop using prewritten textblocks to make your points (as in the first comment), it's kind of rude. ;)